# Unexpected token: "" at column issue in lightning component markup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

[image]

I am getting `Unexpected token: "" at column` issue in lightning component markup.

I am trying to concatenate values of the `aura:attribute`. According to [the](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_operators.htm) documentation:

> + | 'Title: ' + v.note.title | Concatenates two strings together.

So, I would expect my approach to work, but as you see it does not.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get the same problem using single quotes `' '` in the expression? These expressions are not JavaScript but rather salesforce's own expression language. I've only ever used single quotes in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to try it with single quote

```
{!v.ContactInfo.FirstName + ' ' + v.ContactInfo.LastName }
```